# Maven classifier empty jars

Tags: java, maven, build, continuous-integration

Assume we have multimodule maven project:

```
parent
|-module-a-jar
|-module-b-jar
|-web-module-c-war
```

There is common classified specified for parent pom.xml:

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>${my.project.classifier}</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>${my.project.classifier}</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Assume that I build project using

```
mvn clean package -Dmy.project.classifier=NIGHTLY
```

After building **web-module-c-war** contains empty folders instead of jar files:

```
web-module-c-war
|-WEB-INF
  |-lib
    |-module-a-jar
    |-module-a-jar
```

Can you please advise how to fix this? Why this is happening?

If I remove **classifier** from maven-jar-plugin configuration it seems to be working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just make this?

1. pom web-module-c-war :

   ```
   <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
   <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <classifier>${my.project.classifier}</classifier>

   ..
   ..
   <dependency>
       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
       <artifactId>module-a-jar</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version> 
       <classifier>${my.project.classifier}</classifier>
   </dependency> 

   <dependency>
       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
       <artifactId>module-b-jar</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version> 
       <classifier>${my.project.classifier}</classifier>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it seems **maven classifiers** functionality is not a good way to achieve what I want. There is new question created for further clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009281/maven-profile-and-artifact-version