# Maven profile and artifact version

Tags: java, maven, build, continuous-integration, nexus

Assume we have maven multimodule project "Foo":

```
Foo
|-web-module-war
  |-dependency-jar
```

There are two profiles defined for **moduleC**:

```
    <profile>
        <id>poll-some-external-service</id>
        <properties>
            <dependency-jar.poll.configured>true</dependency-jar.poll.configured>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>produce-some-product</id>
        <properties>
            <dependency-jar.poll.configured>false</dependency-jar.poll.configured>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Now we run two builds:

1. mvn clean package -P poll-some-external-service
2. mvn clean package -P produce-some-product

First build produce following artifacts:

```
web-module-war-1.0.0-poll.war
dependency-jar-1.0.0-poll.war
```

Second build produce following artifacts:

```
web-module-war-1.0.0-produce.war
dependency-jar-1.0.0-produce.war
```

This means that **war file** contains web application which works in a different way based on selected **profile**.

Naming is based on the following configuration in the parent pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <jarName>${project.build.finalName}${foo.build.info}</jarName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <warName>${project.build.finalName}${foo.build.info}</warName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

How can I deploy these artifacts into Nexus? -poll/-produce part is stripped during deployment. This means we have two different applications of the same version but we can deploy only one of them

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing the name use a classifier

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>poll</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Your profile for the pom should look similar to the following example. Note that you have to change the dependencies by using the profile too.

```
    <profile>
        <id>poll</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>poll</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dependency-jar</artifactId>
                    <classifier>poll</classifier>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: I don't like idea of introducing classifiers. In fact I've tried it (see my original questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992406/maven-classifier-empty-jars).

Comment: As far as I understand classifiers should be used to attach some artifacts (e.g. java docs, sources) e.g. duplicating artifacts. I'm not really sure if this is correct usage in my case

Comment: You are changing the content of your jar / war, therefore you need some classifier to determine which jar / war you want to use in some other project, otherwise maven doesn't get the versioning right